# How To Create A Parts List In Google SketchUp

Tags: sketchup

I am using Google SketchUp version 7.0.10247 to design a kitchen table that I would like to build.  Once I am done with the design, I'd like be able to produce a parts list that I can print out and use to take to the hardware store.  Has anyone got any experience doing such?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In woodworking, the board material you will need  is typically called a "Cutlist." People have created many plug-ins for SketchUp to create cutlists.

[CutList for SketchUp](http://steveracz.com/joomla/content/view/45/1/) is one example that does this... and it's free.

CutList 4.0 SketchUp plug-in helps you determine how much of each material you need to produce your design, taking into account nominal-sized lumber with allowances for finishing to final size. Then it lays out all of the pieces on boards or sheet good sizes of your choosing.

Comment: This is probably exactly what I am looking for!  Thank you!  I will download and evaluate it.

Comment: This *is* what I have been looking for.  Thank you very much!